# Audio tag works on Android, but not on IOS

Tags: html5-audio

I'm having a problem with the audio tag when I want to autoplay audio on my website. It works on PC, Android but not on iOS. Can someone help me explain?

Comment: You may be coming up against IOS policy not to autoplay - needs a user interaction to start playing.

Comment: Also make sure you use an audio format that is supported on iOS (_eg:_ mp3, m4a).